# Most efficient way to hide multiple elements on click outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

Okay so we all know this way of hiding an element (and multiple elements) when clicking outside of it (i.e. element loses focus):

```
$('document').on('click', function () { $(element).hide(); });

$(element).on('click', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); /* ka-chow! */ });
```

Meaning any click event that reaches the document will hide the element, while any click inside the element will not propagate to the document and will not fire the click event.

That's all nice and well and definitely not news.

However, I have a complex and rich UI. This interface has many elements that require this sort of behavior. Let's assume only one element needs to get hidden on each event for that matter. Would I need to traverse the whole lot every time, to find the one element I want to hide?

If so what is the most efficient way to do it? Give them all a unique class name? Or store each element's classname/ID/DOM instance in an array and loop through that every time? Each solution sounds more inefficient than the other to me.

What would you do?

Comment: Give them all the same class, then it's a one-liner, as in your example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is that definitely the most efficient way to go?

Comment: At the end of the day, it's down to whether you search for the elements to hide, or the browser does.  I would hope the browser can find elements of the page it's displaying faster than your Javascript can.  It wouldn't be beyond the realms of possibility that the browser stores a list of all elements within the CSS class anyway, so it might not have to search at all.  You will always have to search though, or maintain your own list and iterate, which is more work for you - work you don't really have to do.

Comment: So a simple class name is the way to go then. Anybody wants to add it as an answer and get the rep for it?

Comment: "Let's assume only one element needs to get hidden on each event for that matter" - so how many elements will show up at the same time? If over one element displayed at the same time, how do you decide which one should be hidden? Could you provide scenario more details?

Comment: @benbai123 As you just quoted me, only one element. And for that matter, if you want several "layers" of toggling elements, you could give all layers classes such as: `toggle-1`, `toggle-2`, `toggle-3`, and run a descending while loop in the document event handler, breaking the loop when you hide all the layers down to the one you want to keep on. If you want something more complex you have to use some conditionals, I believe.

Comment: If only one element displayed at a time, I think you can store the displayed element and hide that element directly without any iteration?

Comment: Clever. What would you do if there are several elements that are displayed together, covering each other? Use a stack?

Comment: So there might multiple elements displayed at a time but you want close one of them by some rule, my question is, what is the rule?

Comment: There rule is LIFO. Last in - first out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume:

1. Those elements are show/hide by javascript.
2. The rule is the later it is showed up, the earlier it is hidden.

Then I'll maintain an array to handle it, for example:

```
var displayedElements = [];

...

// called when you want to display an element
function showUp (ele) {
    // push element into array
    displayedElements.push(ele);
    ...
}

// called when you want to close the last displayed element
function closeOneIfAvailable () {
    var len = displayedElements.length;
    if (len > 0) {
        var idx = len - 1;
        hideIt (displayedElements[idx]);
        displayedElements.splice(idx, 1);
    }
}

// called when you want to hide an element
function hideIt (ele) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That is so simple and straightforward. Major props!